# Document Outline in AvalonEdit

Tags: c#, avalonedit

I am using the AvalonEdit in my app. In order to provide users better code navigation I am trying to provide a Document Outline of the source code, so I am wondering if AvalonEdit support it provide in in tree style manner.

Edit:
It seems that there are some Highlighting / folding options with .Xshd, which are parsing the source code and generating source folding between brackets. So, my question is how can I use them to exctract methods and properties which later could be included in Listview or Treeview.